# Saving an ngResource with additional query string parameters

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I have a resource in my API called `/foos`. I can create a new Foo by making a `POST` request to this URL.

In the client I use Angular's `ngResource` to deal with API calls. Insertion is easy:

```
var newFoo = new Foo({param1: 'value1'});
newFoo.$save();
```

So far, so good. The API returns the following:

```
{id: 1, param1: "value1"}
```

Now, here's the good part. For the sake of simplicity my API allows to specify which related entities should be returned in the response by means of a query string param, `with`. So:

```
GET /foos/1?with=relatedEntity
```

Would return

```
{id: 1, param1: "value1", relatedEntity: { ... }}
```

This is also accepted in `POST` requests. I'd like to create a Foo and have it returned back with some related entities so that I can use them straight away in my app without the need to perform another request:

```
POST /foos?with=relatedEntity
```

However, I've been unable to achieve this using standard the ngResource `$save()` function.

Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

Our client extends the base `$resource` factory and overrides the `$save()` function, but this implementation was not propagating all the required parameters down the call chain, so no URL params were being sent.